# How to gradually train a model on transformers library?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have seen [this tutorial on how to train a BERT model](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/blog/blob/master/notebooks/01_how_to_train.ipynb#scrollTo=o6sASa36Nf-N) from scratch on Hugging Face Transformers library.

I'm trying to train a GPT-2 model on 1.5 GB data on Google Colab. I load up all the data using this code:

```
dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path="./my-1.5gb-large-file.txt",
    block_size=128,
)
```

The file gets too large, training fails because of limited memory in the GPU. Is there a way I could train my GPT-2 model gradually by splitting the dataset?

Comment: If you're running out of GPU memory, that likely means your batch size is too large rather than the dataset being too large

Comment: @Karl, true... But reducing the batch size may cause overfitting! So I don't want to fall into this risk. Instead, I'm looking at keeping the batch size the same and playing with the amount of loaded data.

Comment: You can reduce batch size and use gradient accumulation. The effect is the same as a larger batch size, but computation can be split across multiple iterations. See [here](https://medium.com/huggingface/training-larger-batches-practical-tips-on-1-gpu-multi-gpu-distributed-setups-ec88c3e51255)

Comment: @MohamedTaherAlrefaie changing the size of the dataset you load will have no impact on GPU memory usage. GPU memory usage is determined by the size of your model and the batch size of training. You don't load the full dataset onto the GPU, just one batch at a time.